# orange limiters when rendering

Tags: rendering

how do I get rid of these orange limiters when rendering?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rendering tile.  In 3.0+ this only happens on high resolution images.  When blender completes all samples on this tile it will move on to the others.  Overall quality will be consistent.

The options can be found here

[image]

Comment: Oh Thank you My Dear!!!I'm quite an experienced user, but it broke my brain))))

Comment: Good to note that before Cycles X rewrite, using tiles was used to drastically reduce render time. But since then, rendering without tiling (or as per default settings: with a tile bigger than the render area) should be faster in many cases.